# How can I avoid color banding in WPF's LinearGradientBrushes?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, colors, linear-gradients

Apart from using images and dithering the gradient in software <s>(or messing around with pixel shaders that do the dithering for me)</s>, what can I do to avoid color banding in monochrome gradients in WPF using .NET 4.6.1?

Related: Is there a way to force WPF to use 16bpc color behind the scenes?

Comment: Is this only happening in monochrome gradients, and only in .NET 4.6?

Comment: By design, color banding is happening in all 8bpc gradients once they get large enough.

Answer (score 1):

A way I've found was to add the gradient to a container, give it a small negative margin so it spills over a little, add a BlurEffect to the gradient, and then turn on ClipToBounds on the parent container. This way the gradient evens out a bit nicer at the expense of performance.

Depending on your use case, this may not be viable, however.

Example:

```
<Grid Height="26" Margin="-5,0" ClipToBounds="True">
    <Grid Margin="-5">
        <Grid.Effect>
            <BlurEffect Radius="6" />
        </Grid.Effect>
        <Grid.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush>
                <GradientStop x:Name="GradientStop7" Color="Magenta" Offset="0.0" />
                <GradientStop x:Name="GradientStop8" Color="DarkOrchid" Offset=".2" />
                <GradientStop x:Name="GradientStop9" Color="Purple" Offset="1" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Grid.Background>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

The negative gradient should be equal to the blur radius so that it doesn't become transparent on the edges.